# Short form for "aujourd'hui"

Tags: indications-de-temps, argot, sms-lingo

Is there an acceptable slang or argot to mean "aujourd'hui" ? I want to use it in chat rooms or emails and I want to use the common standard if there is one.

Comment: *A priori* je ne pense pas qu'il existe de mot d'argot courant pour dire « aujourd'hui ».

Comment: I can’t think of any for the entire 24-hour period, but for talking about specific parts of today you could use “ce mat” and “cette aprèm” for “ce matin” and “cet après-midi” and in the right context people would probably assume that you’re talking about today’s morning and today’s afternoon, respectively.

Comment: Logic would *seem* to suggest the obvious "hui" which **does mean** today and is the basis for the composite "aujourd'hui" pleonasm. Alas, languages don't follow this kind of simplification logic, so... at this point we're still stuck with the long form.

Answer (score 5):

Voir par exemple [cette liste de termes d'argot proposée sur un forum](http://www.translatum.gr/forum/index.php?topic=126107.0).

Comme a noté Toto, je ne connais pas non plus d'argot pour « aujourd'hui », mais je vois souvent sous forme de SMS « **auj** » et comme a dit Random, « **ajd** ».

Comment: "ajd" pour ma part

Comment: Cette liste, quoique intéressante, est un fourre-tout qui mélange l'anglais et le français. Privilégier peut-être la source de la liste, soit la liste des termes d'argot ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_termes_d%27argot_Internet)) et la liste qui s'y rattache au [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Liste_de_termes_d’argot_Internet). Merci.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for slang as many abbreviations are typical, such as [*auj.*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1792) for *aujourd'hui* (see [others](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=abbr%C3%A9viation&T3.x=0&T3.y=0)), and people have been wondering about those before mobile and such. The period is [required](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3401) at the end.

Answer (score 3):

There are no short forms for *aujourd'hui* that are commonly used (to put in contrast with the word *aprèm* short for *après-midi*, afternoon which is very common).

If I were to send "auj./ajd" in a text message or an email to a friend from my engineering school, or a colleague even in a non-professional context, I'm not sure they will understand it instantly, so I'll use the entire word anyways.

If your chat room's users commonly use three, two or one letter words that may include digits (example: `2m1 t ou`), go for it.

Personally I didn't know *auj.* even existed, but if I'd seen this in a mail I'd probably take several seconds to read the context and understand what it meant in retrospect. [@cccg03's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18941/short-form-for-aujourdhui/18942#18942) links to an "internet slang"  resource with lots of such abbreviations, and even though I grew up with mobile phones when I was a teenager there are only about ten words in there I recognize, and for some I understood a completely different meaning (we use *pj* at work but it means *pièce jointe*, email attachment, not *petit joueur*).

Be careful of who the recipient of your messages is, if you use abbreviations or slang the recipient doesn't understand immediately, it defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Though "aujourd'hui" is quite long for sure, it is very spread and there is no real alternative to it. Get used to type it, because you'll do it a lot.

- "auj." could work, but this abbreviation is a bit short, and isn't used that much, so you would need a context that makes really clear you're referring to a day.
- I've never read "ajd.". Don't use that.
- You could use "today", but I'm advocating against Frenglish.

Comment: Je trouve que ce n'est pas mal du tout "aujourd."... C'est très compréhensible et ça montre que l'on en a assez de taper "aujourd'hui". Nous avons peut-être là un nouvel usage à introduire sur les internets :-)

Comment: N'hésitez pas à intégrer cette idée directement dans votre réponse...

Answer (score 1):

Les mots familiers ou d'argot portent rarement sur des termes techniques ou précis comme le temps, des mesures. Ils portent sur des qualificatifs (avec tout ce que cela peut avoir de péjoratif), sur des verbes (toubib, d'origine étrangère en fait), et sur des mots communs d'usage très fréquent (bagnole, ...).

en revanche, on peut trouver des diminutifs, pour simplifier: à + , pour à plus tard.

si on cherche une forme simplifiée, on pourrait employer des termes anglais plus concis:

- *today*
- *now* (approximatif)

Si on veut être subtil, on peut essayer *hui* (pas certain d'être compris).

Comment: *hui* me semble effectivement beaucoup trop érudit et ne sera surement (presque) jamais compris.

Answer (score 1):

Il n'existe pas d'équivalent à `aujourd'hui` dans la langue Française, néanmoins vous pouvez remplacer le mot par `actuellement / maintenant (now)`.

Par SMS l'utilisation de `ajd` reste rare, `auj` trés rare (jamais vu).